# pass dataframe column as parameter in xpath

Tags: xpath, pyspark

I am using xpath in pyspark to extract from xml which is stored as a column in a table.

**Below works fine**

```py
entity_id="D8"
                               
dfquestionstep=df_source_xml.selectExpr("disclosure_entity_id",       
      f'xpath(**xml**,"*/entities/entity[@type=\'TI\']/entity[@type=\'UNDERWRITING\']/entity[@type=\'DISCLOSURES\']/entity[**@id=\'{entity_id}\'**]/entity[@type=\'DECISION_PATH\']/entity[@type=\'QUESTION_STEP\']/@id") QUESTION_STEP_ID' 
     )
```

**PROBLEM**

Now I want to pass `disclosure_entity_id` which is a column in dataframe having values like D8, D9 etc. in place of entity_id, i.e. entity[**@id=disclosure_entity_id**]

But all I get is `[]` as result when I execute like this, i.e. xpath fails to find anything.

Is there a way to pass the DF column directly as argument to XPATH like above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some testdata:**

```python
data = [
  ['a','<x><a>a1</a><b>b1</b><c>c1</c></x>'],
  ['b','<x><a>a2</a><b>b2</b><c>c2</c></x>'],
  ['c','<x><a>a3</a><b>b3</b><c>c3</c></x>'],
    ]
    
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['col','data'])
```

**Attempt 1:**

Creating a column with an XPath expression can be done:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

df.withColumn('my_path', f.concat(f.lit('//'), f.col('col'))) \
  .selectExpr('xpath(data, my_path)').show()
```

But unfortunately the code above only yields the error message

```
AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'xpath(`data`, `my_path`)' due to data type mismatch: 
path should be a string literal; line 1 pos 0;
```

The path parameter of the [xpath](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/sql/index.html#xpath) function has to be a constant string. This string is parsed before Spark even looks at the data.

**Attempt 2:**

Another option is to use an [udf](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.udf.html) and use [standard Python functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) to process the XPath expression inside of the udf:

```python
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from pyspark.sql import types as T

def find_val(col, data): 
  result= ET.fromstring(data).find(f'.//{col}')
  if not result is None:
    return result.text

find_val_udf=f.udf(find_val, returnType=T.StringType())

df.select('col', 'data',  find_val_udf('col', 'data')).show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+---+----------------------------------+-------------------+
|col|data                              |find_val(col, data)|
+---+----------------------------------+-------------------+
|a  |<x><a>a1</a><b>b1</b><c>c1</c></x>|a1                 |
|b  |<x><a>a2</a><b>b2</b><c>c2</c></x>|b2                 |
|c  |<x><a>a3</a><b>b3</b><c>c3</c></x>|c3                 |
+---+----------------------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Appreciate the help werner,from your answer and most importantly the sample code I was able to frame my solution in the desired manner.Thanks a lot!!